# C++, how do I enable access of a unique member of a derived class, after I initialized it using a base class pointer?

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

So I was just wandering if there is a way to access a unique member of a derived class that is not declared in the base class after I initialize it using a base class pointer... see the code below.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    int valueBase = 10;
};

class B: public A{
public:
    int valueDerived = 20;
};

int main(){

    A* obj = new B();

    cout<<obj->valueBase<<endl;
    // all okay
    
    cout<<obj->valueDerived<<endl;
    // error: ‘class A’ has no member named ‘valueDerived’ 

    return 0;
}
```

here I want to access the "valueDerived" member in the 'derived class'... The idea was, I was planning to make different classes that inherits the base class 'A', and also have different data type of 'valueDerived' for each  derived classes, or is there a much better way to do this in C++?

PS: I don't want to use templates since It can get really ugly when dealing with method definitions that are in different source files

Comment: if `A` is polymorphic you could `dynamic_cast` the `obj` pointer to a `B*` then, if the cast succeeded, use it to access `valueDerived`. Otherwise you could force it with `static_cast` though that would fail miserably if `obj` were *not* a `B` pointer. But there is not enough context to advise what the best way may be.

Comment: When a `B` is masquerading as an `A` it can only do `A` things. At runtime the `A*` might be pointing to a `C` or some other class that [is-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `A` but otherwise has nothing in common with a `B`. You have to go with the lowest common denominator. I generally prefer to broaden that lowest common denominator by adding a `virtual` method to `A that is implemented by `B` and `B`'s siblings, but that may not jive with what you have in mind for `A`.

Comment: Often this type of question indicates inferior class design. If you have a pointer to `A`, why do you need to access something of `B`? If you need to access something of `B`, why do you have a pointer to `A` instead of a pointer to `B`?

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer to your question is that you can explicitly downcast the pointer to a `B*`. For the sample you've given you'd have to use a `static_cast`, but if your base class included any virtual functions (such as a virtual destructor, which is strongly recommended if you'll be destroying derived classes through base class pointers) then you'd be able to use `dynamic_cast`.

That said, it sounds like what you really want is to be able to ask an object known only as the base class to return a value that depends on which derived class it really is. Virtual functions do that, so I suggest you read up on them.